# Race condition against Google Photos API

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm developing [this CLI](https://github.com/gphotosuploader/gphotos-uploader-cli) to upload images to Google Photos. The CLI creates several go routines to upload files in parallel [1](https://github.com/gphotosuploader/gphotos-uploader-cli/blob/8a9ac28015976623da7bb7efcba9c9aa7619c411/upload/enqueue.go#L22). Once it's uploaded, the same routine adds it to an `Album`. These albums are created if they didn't exist before [2](https://github.com/gphotosuploader/gphotos-uploader-cli/blob/8a9ac28015976623da7bb7efcba9c9aa7619c411/upload/enqueue.go#L54).

Due to the concurrency and the fact that **Google Photos API allows the creation of two `Albums` with the same name**, I'm having duplicated album names that I'd like to avoid.

The `GetOrCreateAlbumByName()` [3](https://github.com/gphotosuploader/google-photos-api-client-go/blob/bdfcf26e6f640f768fe745bc6ead8627df10b68a/lib-gphotos/albums.go#L64) doesn't ensure that the `Album` is unique. It basically ask if an album exists with the same name and if not, it will create a new one. But this function could be called in parallel so two `Album` with the same name could be created. Besides it's implementing a mutex, I'm observing duplicates.

**How would yo recommend to deal with that?**

1. Create a Worker (like a microservice) that deal with album creation. Each go routine will be blocked until the album is created. It will remove concurrency on the `Album` creation part.
2. Maintain an *album cache* and use it to check if the album has been already created. In that case, race condition could happen too, but with less probability.
3. Using 1 and 2 together.
4. Other, please specify.

I have concerns about 1, 2 and 3... that's why I would like to know how you would deal with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you use [`Client.GetOrCreateAlbum()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gphotosuploader/google-photos-api-client-go@v1.1.5/lib-gphotos?tab=doc#Client.GetOrCreateAlbumByName) which doesn't create a duplicate if the album already exists. What's the problem?

Comment: Please give more details so we don't have to go through your entire app. A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: I've edit the question to include the parts of the code that I think will explain better the problem.

Comment: `Client.GetOrCreateAlbumByName()` uses mutex so concurrent calls don't create duplicates, but your code (may) create and use multiple clients, each having its own mutex, so they still may create dupliates. Use a single `Client`. Or if you must use multiple clients, use a single mutex or other means to serialize all `GetOrCreateAlbumByName()` calls.

Comment: So that solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`Client.GetOrCreateAlbumByName()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gphotosuploader/google-photos-api-client-go@v1.1.5/lib-gphotos?tab=doc#Client.GetOrCreateAlbumByName) to get or create albums. This method is safe for concurrent use, and it uses a mutex internally to serialize calls, which ensures duplicates are not created.

However, you are creating and using multiple clients [here](https://github.com/gphotosuploader/gphotos-uploader-cli/blob/8a9ac28015976623da7bb7efcba9c9aa7619c411/cmd/push.go#L80), which means concurrent calls to all of them is not serialized, only concurrent calls to individual clients.

So the solution to either use a single client, then all calls will be serialized, or if that's not possible, you have to serialize calls to all clients, e.g. using a single mutex or other means.

An example how to serialize calls to all clients with a mutex:

```
var mu sync.Mutex

func GetOrCreateAlbumByName(c *gphotos.Client, name string) (*photoslibrary.Album, error) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    return c.GetOrCreateAlbumByName(name)
}
```

And wherever you use `client.GetOrCreateAlbumByName(name)`, replace it with the call:

```
GetOrCreateAlbumByName(client, name)
```